# How to find last Monday of two months ago's or N months ago

Tags: php, date

I can find last Monday of previous month, but I need also two months ago's last Monday?

```
strtotime("last Monday of June 2015") //gives previous month's last Monday
```

What should I do to find -2 month's last Monday?

I will use this programmatically

Comment: Did you try `last monday of two months ago`?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Past
strtotime("last Monday of -2 months");

// Future
strtotime("last Monday of +2 months");
```

Works like a charm! PHP's `strtotime` is very smart.

Comment: Cleaner than my answer, trickiest part of doing things like this is trying to work out how to word the string in strtotime()

Comment: Haha Is there someone who has shorter than this answer :D

Comment: [*Relative Time Formats*](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) are great!! And this is a nice example of how great they are! :)

Comment: All answes are great but I choosed this answer, because it is shortest and simplest I think.

Comment: Pelase add +2 moths example for future times.:)

Answer (score 2):

Dirty in my opinion, but this works

```
$no_months = -2; // Number of months from now
echo date('d/M/Y' , strtotime('Last monday of ' . date('M Y', strtotime($no_months . ' months'))));
```

Essentially this just dynamically creates the " June 2015", " May 2015" part of your original string, depending on the negative/positive value of months you set in the var.

Comment: Also you can add an example for future times like `$no_months = 3` for other people. :)